# Pre-filled Database Error in Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, database, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

My application (platform 1.5) has a prefilled database. The Sqlite file was larger than 5mb so I split it into small files smaller than 950KB and put them into Assets.

When I first install app, it copies all these files into one database file.
It works well in my own phone (Samsung GalaxyS 2.2). However, I tried it in a samsung gt-s5830i  2.3.6 and while it is loading the database, it collapses.

I do not know why it does not work. Please help me.

Here is my code:

public class SQLiteDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.android.appname/databases/";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "db.sqlite";
    private static final String ASSETS_DB_FOLDER = "db";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;


    public SQLiteDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }


    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and overwrite it with your own
     * database.
     **/
    public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            super.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDatabase();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDatabase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY|SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        String[] dbFiles = myContext.getAssets().list(ASSETS_DB_FOLDER);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        for(int i =0; i < dbFiles.length; i++) {
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(ASSETS_DB_FOLDER+"/"+dbFiles[i]);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myInput.close();
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY|SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null) myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { }

    @Override
    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase (){
        try {
            createDatabase();
            openDatabase();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            myDataBase = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            myDataBase = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myDataBase;
    }
}
```

Comment: "it collapse" is a completely useless explanation. Please consider [using `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) instead of rolling this yourself.

Comment: very helpful library but I have same result. in some phones it works, does not work in others. Why it does not work in some phone? did I miss smth? btw, my database contains UTF-8 characters. can it cause problems?